# Sort elements in list by enum value or string value

Tags: java, sorting, arraylist, java-8

I want to sort an `ArrayList` in ascending order and in descending order by comparing a String value or an Enum value.

This is the ArrayList I want to sort :

```
List<Issue> issues;
```

The list will be sorted depending on two params (`field` and `sort`) I give to a function :

```
private List<Issue> sortList(List<Issue> list, String field, String sort) {
    // My code goes here
}
```

So let's assume that the `field` value is `title` and the `sort` values is `DESC` then I want to order all `Issue` elements in the list by their `title` filed, this is what I tried :

```
return list.stream().sorted((i1, i2) -> String.compare(i2.getTitle(), i1.getTitle())).collect(Collectors.toList());
```

But this generates the following error :

```
The method compare(String, String) is undefined for the type String
```

For the enums I couldn't figure out how to compare their values.

How can I solve this ?

## Classes definition :

**Issue** :

```
public class Issue {

    private IssueElementEnum issueElement;
    private IssueTypeEnum issueType;
    private String title;

    // Getters and setters
}
```

**IssueElementEnum**:

```
public enum IssueElementEnum {
    PROFILE {

        @Override
        public String toString() {
            return "Profil";
        }
    }
    ROLE {

        @Override
        public String toString() {
            return "Rôle";
        }
    },
    User {

        @Override
        public String toString() {
            return "Utilisateur";
        }
    }
}
```

**IssueTypeEnum**:

```
public enum IssueTypeEnum {
    PROFILE {

        @Override
        public String toString() {
            return "Sans Profil";
        }
    },
    ROLE {

        @Override
        public String toString() {
            return "Sans Rôle";
        }
    },
    USER {

        @Override
        public String toString() {
            return "Sans Utilisateur";
        }
    }
}
```

## Edit :

Sometimes I want to sort my list with more than one field, for example (sort the list by `title` in ascending order and then by `issueElement.toSting()` in descending order, for that I created the following class :

```
public class SortDTO implements ISort {

    public static final String ASC = "ASC";
    public static final String DESC = "DESC";

    private String field;

    private String sort;


    public GridSortDTO() {
        this(null, null);
    }

    public GridSortDTO(final String field, final String sort) {
        super();
        this.field = field;
        this.sort = sort;
    }

    @Override
    public String getField() {
        return field;
    }

    @Override
    public void setField(final String field) {
        this.field = field;
    }

    @Override
    public String getSort() {
        return sort;
    }

    @Override
    public void setSort(final String type) {
        this.sort = type;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return String.format("Sort[field=%s, sort=%s]", this.field, this.sort);
    }
}

public interface ISort {

    String getField();

    void setField(final String field);

    String getSort();

    void setSort(final String type);
}
```

Then my sort informations are stored in this array : `GridSortDTO[] sorts`.

So for example `sorts` will contain this information :

```
[{"field":"title","sort":"asc"},{"field":"issueElement","sort":"desc"}]
```

How can I implement this ?

Comment: replace `String.compare(i2.getTitle(), i1.getTitle()))` by `i2.getTitle().compareTo(i1.getTitle())`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It’s not clear which order you want for the `enum` types, declaration order (`PROFILE, ROLE, USER`) or lexicographic order of their `toString()` representation.

In the latter case, you could implement the method as

```
private List<Issue> sortList(List<Issue> list, String field, String sort) {
    Function<Issue,String> f;
    switch(field) {
        case "Title": f = Issue::getTitle; break;
        case "IssueElement": f = i -> i.getIssueElement().toString(); break;
        case "IssueType": f = i -> i.getIssueType().toString(); break;
        default: throw new IllegalArgumentException("unknown property '"+field+"'");
    }
    Comparator<Issue> cmp = Comparator.comparing(f);
    if("DESC".equalsIgnoreCase(sort)) cmp = cmp.reversed();
    else if(!"ASC".equalsIgnoreCase(sort))
        throw new IllegalArgumentException("invalid sort '"+sort+"'");
    return list.stream().sorted(cmp).collect(Collectors.toList());
}
```

If you want to use the `enum` declaration order instead, you have slightly less common code:

```
private List<Issue> sortList(List<Issue> list, String field, String sort) {
    Comparator<Issue> cmp;
    switch(field) {
        case "Title": cmp = Comparator.comparing(Issue::getTitle); break;
        case "IssueElement": cmp = Comparator.comparing(Issue::getIssueElement); break;
        case "IssueType": cmp = Comparator.comparing(Issue::getIssueType); break;
        default: throw new IllegalArgumentException("unknown property '"+field+"'");
    }
    if("DESC".equalsIgnoreCase(sort)) cmp = cmp.reversed();
    else if(!"ASC".equalsIgnoreCase(sort))
        throw new IllegalArgumentException("invalid sort '"+sort+"'");
    return list.stream().sorted(cmp).collect(Collectors.toList());
}
```

Instead of the `switch` statement, you could also maintain a map of existing orders, which offers more flexibility:

```
// in Java 9, you should replace Arrays.asList(...) with List.of(...)
static final Map<List<String>,Comparator<Issue>> ORDER;
static {
    Map<List<String>,Comparator<Issue>> m = new HashMap<>();
    Comparator<Issue> c = Comparator.comparing(Issue::getTitle);
    m.put(Arrays.asList("Title", "asc"), c);
    m.put(Arrays.asList("Title", "desc"), c.reversed());
    c = Comparator.comparing(Issue::getIssueElement);
    m.put(Arrays.asList("IssueElement", "asc"), c);
    m.put(Arrays.asList("IssueElement", "desc"), c.reversed());
    c = Comparator.comparing(Issue::getIssueType);
    m.put(Arrays.asList("IssueType", "asc"), c);
    m.put(Arrays.asList("IssueType", "desc"), c.reversed());
    ORDER = Collections.unmodifiableMap(m);
}
private List<Issue> sortList(List<Issue> list, String field, String sort) {
    Comparator<Issue> cmp = ORDER.get(Arrays.asList(field, sort.toLowerCase(Locale.ROOT)));
    if(cmp == null)
        throw new IllegalArgumentException("property '"+field+"', sort '"+sort+"'");
    return list.stream().sorted(cmp).collect(Collectors.toList());
}
```

---

This approach can be adapted to your new requirement, though, I strongly suggest a slight redesign:

```
enum Direction { ASCENDING, DESCENDING }
public interface ISort {
    String getField();
    void setField(final String field);
    Direction getSort();
    void setSort(final Direction type);
}
```

Adapting the implementation is straight-forward, but you should avoid allowing `null` for the sorting direction, as then, it’s intrisically only either of the two legal values:

```
public class SortDTO implements ISort {
    private String field;
    private Direction sort;
    public SortDTO() { this(null, Direction.ASCENDING); }
    public SortDTO(String field, Direction sort) {
        this.field = field;
        this.sort = sort;
    }
    public String getField() { return field; }
    public void setField(String field) { this.field = field; }
    public Direction getSort() { return sort; }
    public void setSort(Direction sort) { this.sort = Objects.requireNonNull(sort); }
    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return String.format("Sort[field=%s, sort=%s]", this.field, this.sort);
    }
}
```

We augment these types with an immutable key type capable of capturing the current state of an `ISort` implementation and having proper `equals` and `hashCode` implementations:

```
final class SortKey {
    final String field;
    final Direction direction;
    private SortKey(String f, Direction d) { field=f; direction=d; }
    @Override
    public int hashCode() {
        return field.hashCode()*2+direction.ordinal();
    }
    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object obj) {
        if(this == obj) return true;
        if(!(obj instanceof SortKey)) return false;
        SortKey that = (SortKey)obj;
        return this.direction == that.direction && this.field.equals(that.field);
    }
    static SortKey of(String field, Direction dir) {
        return new SortKey(Objects.requireNonNull(field), Objects.requireNonNull(dir));
    }
    static SortKey of(ISort s) {
        return of(s.getField(), s.getSort());
    }
}
```

Then, the adapted solution may look like

```
static final Map<SortKey,Comparator<Issue>> ORDER;
static {
    Map<SortKey,Comparator<Issue>> m = new HashMap<>();
    Comparator<Issue> c = Comparator.comparing(Issue::getTitle);
    m.put(SortKey.of("Title", Direction.ASCENDING), c);
    m.put(SortKey.of("Title", Direction.DESCENDING), c.reversed());
    c = Comparator.comparing(Issue::getIssueElement);
    m.put(SortKey.of("IssueElement", Direction.ASCENDING), c);
    m.put(SortKey.of("IssueElement", Direction.DESCENDING), c.reversed());
    c = Comparator.comparing(Issue::getIssueType);
    m.put(SortKey.of("IssueType", Direction.ASCENDING), c);
    m.put(SortKey.of("IssueElement", Direction.DESCENDING), c.reversed());
    ORDER = Collections.unmodifiableMap(m);
}
private List<Issue> sortList(List<Issue> list, ISort... order) {
    if(order.length == 0) return new ArrayList<>(list);
    Comparator<Issue> cmp = ORDER.get(SortKey.of(order[0]));
    if(cmp == null) throw new IllegalArgumentException(order[0].toString());
    for(int ix = 1; ix < order.length; ix++) {
        Comparator<Issue> next = ORDER.get(SortKey.of(order[ix]));
        if(next == null) throw new IllegalArgumentException(order[ix].toString());
        cmp = cmp.thenComparing(next);
    }
    return list.stream().sorted(cmp).collect(Collectors.toList());
}
```

This allows an arbitrary number of sort criteria, the first being the primary order, the second being the secondary order and so on.

Comment: Thanks for your help, please check my edit for more informations.

Comment: @Eugene: well, the traditional factors are prime numbers and `2` *is* a prime number. It’s unusual indeed, but justified here, as the sorting direction has only two possible values and its hash code truly is either, zero or one. Using a higher factor would not improve the hash code here or even make it worse.

Comment: @Eugene: my bad, it should be `ordinal()` here, to be sure that the value is zero or one. This hash code implementation may eliminate one bit of the string’s hash code, but that’s acceptable as string hash collisions are unlikely, whereas it is even *known* that we will store combinations of the same `field` with either `direction` value in the map, so the used formula guarantees that these values have distinct hash codes.

Comment: @Holger but then, even without this multiply by two you would still get distinct hashCodes

Comment: @Eugene: there is the theoretical chance that the hash code of one `field` string is `x` and the hash code of another is `x+1`, creating collisions when being combined with `direction` by just adding or xoring. The way it has been written now, there can only be a collision if the string hash codes truly collide in the lower 31 bit. Anyway, it’s not worth thinking too long about these tiny differences…

Comment: I appreciate your help but unfortunately I can't change `ISort` and `SortDTO` since I've used them in many places in my project and changing them will cost a lot of time replacing the old code.

Comment: It shouldn’t be too hard to keep a `String` type for the `sort` property rather than changing it to an `enum`, if you understood what my solution does. If there’s something unclear, feel free to ask.

Comment: In the `SortKey`, to calculate the hash code you are using `direction.ordinal()`, using a String instead of an Enum how can I calculate the hash code ?

Comment: Just use `field.hashCode()*31+direction.hashCode()`. Or `Objects.hash(field, direction)` (`java.util.Objects`). Also keep in mind to change the equality to use `equals`, i.e. from `this.direction == that.direction && this.field.equals(that.field)` to `this.direction.equals(that.direction) && this.field.equals(that.field)`.

Comment: This worked for the string fields but it didn't work for the enum fileds, so when initializing comparators I used this instead : `f = i -> i.getIssueElement().toString(); c = Comparator.comparing(f);`  and the same thing for the other enum, but unfortunately it didn't work too the sorting only works for the String field.

Comment: `Comparator.comparing(Issue::getIssueElement)` sorts by the *declaration order* of the constants within the `enum` whereas `Comparator.comparing(i -> getIssueElement().toString())` sorts them by their `toString()` representation. Which variant of my solutions are you referring to (i.e. I have no `f` in my last variant) and what precise issue do you have?

Comment: Oh I just misunderstood, now all is looking good, and it works like a charm, Thanks for your time, I appreciate your help :)

Answer (score 2):

Actually, the method to compare two strings that you are trying to use is `compareTo` and not `compare`, which is defined in the `Comparable` interface. Take a look in the javadoc: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html

Answer (score 2):

If you want to sort your list by the `title` just use the following:

```
stream().sorted(Comparator.comparing(Issue::getTitle)).collect(Collectors.toList())
```

Please have a look at java-8 [Comparator](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Comparator.html)

Comment: This will sort the list in ascending order, how can I sort it in descending order

Comment: just add `reversed` : `sorted(Comparator.comparing(Issue::getTitle).reversed())`